# Adding a Jquery Plugin to an Angular 2 project

Tags: jquery, angular

I am trying to add this [Jquery plugin](https://zurb.com/playground/twentytwenty) to my Angular2 project.

I have added the files to `"src/assets"` also  in `index.html` I've added `<script src="assets/jquery.twentywenty.js"></script>` and `declare var twentytwenty: any;`

I am getting

> jquery.twentytwenty.js:152 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not 
>       defined at jquery.twentytwenty.js:152

also

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'twentytwenty' of undefined

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally apply below steps for using `jquery` plugins in my projects; maybe helpful.

1 - Adding `jquery` and `plugin` files path in `angular-cli.json` (`scripts` section).

```
  "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "assets/vendor/plugin/jquery.plugin.js"
  ]
```

2 -  Declaring `jquery` variable in component.

```
declare let $: any;
```

3 - Using the plugin syntax.

```
(<any>$('#theId')).plugin();
```