# Angular 5 - include jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, angular, import, angular5, angular-cli

Im new to angular, currently working with version 5. I have to install a plugin called 'jquery-circle-progress', which can be found here:
http://kottenator.github.io/jquery-circle-progress/

I've installed it with via npm, and added the .js file to .angular-cli.json scripts array. It seems to load fine, and I can activate it with jquery via browsers console, so this part is ok.

I just dont know how to run it from inside the component. I have to update this progress bar every minute or so, so I wanna make a function in **mycomponent.component.ts**, which fetches some data, checks it, and runs some jquery to update the progress bar.

I just cant get this progress-bar's function to be available here. It just says that '.circleProgress is not available'.

BTW I can get jquery to run inside of the .ts file, via:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

I dont know how to also get circle progress bar in here.

Any help is more than welcome.

Comment: There are a few Angular circular progress bar libraries out there such as https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar -- do any of these work for you?

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768087/adding-a-jquery-plugin-to-an-angular-2-project/48768589#48768589

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the plugin code in your `angular.json` (used to be angular-cli.json) file in scripts array:

```
"scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/nouislider/distribute/nouislider.min.js",
]
```

As you can see above, you can also import jQuery in there - first node module. The next is a jQuery plugin I had to use in my project.

Then create a new Angular wrapper component that will hold the jQuery plugin and initialise it in `ngOnInit()` method and eventually do the cleanup in `ngOnDestroy()` method.
At the top of your component drop this `declare var $:any;` 
You don't have to use `import * as $ from 'jquery';` since `jQuery` is imported into your app in `angular.json` file.